# Remove only one div with query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw2Sn/)

I have a button that will add a new header, textbox, and a link when it's click.

But when I click on the remove link. It's removes every new item that was added.

Html:

```
<div id='main'>
Top of Boby
    <div id='main_1'>
        <div>
            <h3> Item</h3>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.AddItem').click(function() {
        $('div#main_1').append("<div><h3>Item</h3><input type='text' class='remove_skill'/><a href=''>Remove</a</div>");
    });
})
$(function() {
    $('.remove_skill').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

Comment: Where is `.remove_skill`?

Comment: I would suggest you to use `.innerHTML` or even `.html()` instead of `.append()`. This is better performance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code you've posted is that no links exist at the moment you call `$('.remove_skill').click`, so you can't add event listeners to them.

I recommend a step-by-step approach. Create, add behaviour, append to the document.

```
$('.AddItem').click(function () {
    var new_element = $('<div class="item"><h3>Item</h3><input type="text"/><a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></div>');
    new_element.find(".remove").click(remove_item);
    $('div#main_1').append(new_element);
});

function remove_item() {
    $(this).closest(".item").remove();
    return false;
}
```

I recommend `<a href="#">` for javascript-handled links.

Alternative solution using a closure:

```
$('.AddItem').click(function () {
    var new_element = $("<div class="item"><h3>Item</h3><input type='text'/><a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a</div>");
    new_element.find(".remove").click(function() {
        new_element.remove();
    });
    $('div#main_1').append(new_element);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

2 issues..

You have never defined the **class for the anchor**. Add the class to the anchor

You need to `remove the enclosing div` and n`ot the anchor.` Use `.closest`

Also you need to **delegate the event as the elements are being added dynamically**

```
 $('#main').on('click', '.remove_skill',  function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Zw2Sn/7/)**

Comment: Also: The **anchor** tag is not closed properly in the `append()` process.

Comment: true.. That has to be fixed as well

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your "Remove" is in an 'a' tag. This causes the page to reload, and removing all of your previous changes.